# Export from Kony Studio to Visualizer - Duplicate Skins Error

Tags: temenos-quantum

Trying to export a kony studio project back to Visualizer and i can see the below error, can anyone help understand what does this mean ? how did so many duplicate skins occur at the first place and how to delete them without knowing the impact.

Error :- Following problems are found in "BestBuy" project. Follow the instruction below before exporting to Visualizer.

Screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your using kony studio 6.5 the best way to import is below.

1. Design your app in kony visualizer, test it using static data for mobile App and web using preview app.
2. Export your visualizer project from export option in visualizer. this will create a zip file ( you choose the location on your computer as per your comfort )
3. Go to Kony studio, Inside the studio editor you will find "import from visualizer option, use this option only to import all your zip files from visualizer. once imported you can work on it.
4. if you need any changes to your UI in kony studio, you cannot do it here, you will have to export the project from studio as "export to visualizer" , this is done using a simple right click and export as "export to visualizer". this will again create a zip file ( you choose the location on your computer as per your comfort )
5. open visualizer and import the same zip , make the ui changes and keep following the same steps.

Merge option :- DO not use the merge option as it may lead to loss of your code and does not work in the expected way yet.

doing above will ensure your code changes / UI changes are not lost. But unfortunately you will have to keep doing this back and forth approach in kony 6.5.